# How to get a plain http request

Tags: servlets

a third party service says my service is miss configures
how can I get the plain text of a request on a servlet? I need to show what my service is well configured
any idea?

[Edit] here code:

```
System.out.println(request.getMethod() + " " + request.getPathInfo() + "" + request.getProtocol());
Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
    System.out.println(headerName + ": " + request.getHeader(headerName));
}
Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames(); 
while(params.hasMoreElements()){
    String paramName = params.nextElement();
    System.out.print(paramName+"="+request.getParameter(paramName));
    if(params.hasMoreElements()){
        System.out.print("&");
    }
}
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line);
}
String data = buffer.toString();
System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: I tried show params my third party service sends, but I got null

Comment: Please share your code if you have any, which you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, nothing beats a packet sniffer such as Wireshark. Take the time to install it and learn how to use it - it will save you a lot of time when doing web development.